# Angular CanDeactivateGuard: How to wait for the right or the next value of an Obersavble?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular9, candeactivate

I have a Service that emits events:

```
export class MyService {
  private event = new BehaviorSubject<string>('init');
  event$ = this.event.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  update(): void {
    this.event.next('update');
  }

  accept(): void {
    this.event.next('accept');
  }

  decline(): void {
    this.event.next('decline');
  }
}
```

I also have a `CanDeactivateGuard` that is triggered by a function in a Component:

```
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.service.event$.pipe(
    map(action => {
      return action === 'accept';
    })
  )
}
```

Now this works all fine. But I've got an issue:

This will always return the last event. So when nothing happened it will send `init` immediately. If `update()` was called, it will send `update` directly.

*How can I make this to work so that it either:*

- … waits until `accept` or `decline` is send?
- … waits until the next fresh Event is emitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the first emission from your `BehaviorSubject` with `skip`:

```
this.service
  .pipe(
    skip(1),
    filter(a => ['accept', 'decline'].includes(a))
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving initial events because it is a BehaviorSubject.

You are receiving all events because you are not filtering them out.

How you approach this depends on what purpose(s) event$ is serving. If it is important to emit all events, including the initial state, then definitely leave it as a behavior subject.

I would filter the events in the guard:

```
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.service.event$.pipe(
    filter(action => action === 'accept' || action === 'decline'),
    map(action => {
      return action === 'accept';
    })
  );
}
```

This has the effect of ignoring everything that isn't 'accept' or 'decline'.

Comment: Thank you so much. `filter()` did the trick. In combination with `skip(1)` this is just perfect. Thank you so much.